# Notebook style which imitates Latex paper

Tags: notebooks, stylesheet, latex, style

I have not experimented with Notebook styles, but from what I understand they can be customized to a wide range of styles. Is there a style which looks like a typical paper written in TeX/LaTeX?

My idea here is that instead of writing a paper in TeX/LaTeX, I would write it Mathematica using a LaTeX style, then just output the LaTeX encoding for the notebook and it would be ready for publication.

The biggest problem I guess would be with the plots. Most people seem to use PGF-Tikz, Gnuplot or PGFPlots to generate plots for their LaTeX papers, but if I use Mathematica, I guess I would just have to use an image output.

Comment: If you're looking to write a traditional static publication, where there's no need for interactivity, then there is no advantage using *Mathematica*. There once was hope that it would become a publishing tool, but that hope is about as dead as the [Publicon](https://www.wolfram.com/products/publicon/) page. I always tell people to use [Lyx](http://www.lyx.org/) instead.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a request for capabilities that Mathematica does not have.